# incomplete gamma function with negative arguments

Tags: gamma-function

Does the Gamma function with negative arguments exist?
$\Gamma(\Delta,-\Lambda x)$ 
where $\Delta$ is a negative integer and $\Lambda$ is a positive real number.

thanks!

Comment: *Perhaps*, the solution is here http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.0349. Let us know.